# Verilog assignment result in 'x' in LHS while RHS has a valid value

Tags: encryption, verilog

I have been stuck with this problem for two days and I can't solve it.
In this verilog encryption code I have an assignment in this line: `sumOut = out`, when I try to debug it using ModelSim, the net `out` has a valid value, but `sumOut` stays undefined `x`.
This is the code:

```
`include "adder.v"

module processData(dataOut0, dataOut1, dataIn0, dataIn1, key0, key1, key2, key3, sumIn, sumOut, delta, clk, rst, finish);

output reg [1:32] dataOut0, dataOut1, sumOut;
output reg finish;

input [1:32] dataIn0, dataIn1, key0, key1, key2, key3, sumIn, delta;
input clk, rst;

reg [1:32] in1, in2, first, second, third, tsum;
wire [1:32] out;

integer cnt;

adder add(out, in1, in2);

always @(posedge clk or negedge rst)
begin
    if(!rst)
    begin
        cnt = 0;
        finish = 0;
        //sumOut = 0;
    end
    else
    begin
        if(cnt == 0)
        begin
            in1 = sumIn; 
            in2 = delta;
            sumOut = out;
            cnt = cnt + 1;
        end
        else if(cnt == 1)
        begin
            in1 = dataIn1 << 4;
            in2 = key0;
            first = out;
            cnt = cnt + 1;
        end
        else if(cnt == 2)
        begin
            in1 = dataIn1; 
            in2 = sumOut;
            second = out;
            cnt = cnt + 1;
        end
        else if(cnt == 3)
        begin
            in1 = dataIn1 >> 5;
            in2 = key1;
            third = out;
            cnt = cnt + 1;
        end
        else if(cnt == 4)
        begin
            tsum = first ^ second ^ third;
            cnt = cnt + 1;
        end
        else if(cnt == 5)
        begin 
            in1 = tsum;
            in2 = dataIn0;
            dataOut0 = out;
            cnt = cnt + 1;
        end
        else if(cnt == 6)
        begin
            in1 = dataOut0 << 4;
            in2 = key2;
            first = out;
            cnt = cnt + 1;
        end
        else if(cnt == 7)
        begin
            in1 = dataOut0; 
            in2 = sumOut;
            second = out;
            cnt = cnt + 1;
        end
        else if(cnt == 8)
        begin
            in1 = dataOut0 >> 5;
            in2 = key3;
            third = out;
            cnt = cnt + 1;
        end
        else if(cnt == 9)
        begin
            tsum = first ^ second ^ third;
            cnt = cnt + 1;
        end
        else if(cnt == 10)
        begin 
            in1 = tsum;
            in2 = dataIn1;
            dataOut1 = out;
            cnt = cnt + 1;
        end
        else if(cnt == 11)
        begin
            finish = 1;
        end
    end
end
endmodule
```

Comment: Do you reset on every activation of this module? `cnt` is set to zero only when `!rst`. This seems like a strange way for a circuit to function. Consider adding `cnt = 0` to the `cnt == 11` case. Or some other activation signal that will set `cnt = 0`.

Comment: Does `sumOut` have any other drivers? I forget how you check this in ModelSim - something like right-click, trace drivers.

Comment: You should be using the `<=` (non-blocking) assignment operator rather than the `=` assignment operator, especially in this clocked always block.  Here's more information on [blocking vs. nonblocking in Verilog](http://www.nandland.com/articles/blocking-nonblocking-verilog.html)

Comment: Yes, I do reset this in an upper module every time, setting `cnt=0` will make the simulation run forever in a loop. @Hida

Comment: No, it doesn't have any other drivers. @EML

Comment: But if I use non-blocking assignment my code will be wrong, as you see I have instantiated a module `adder` where it adds 2 registers. I can't be using non-blocking assignments because I need the assignments to assigned in serial. @Russell

Comment: @Zana: if you are debugging with ModelSim, *and* you are stepping over `sumOut=out`, *and* `out` has a valid value, and `sumOut` takes the value `x`, then you are 99% guaranteed that `sumOut` has another driver. If you are not doing these things, then you need to clarify your question. Have you actually used modelsim to check your drivers? On Russell's comment: you must fix your code to use non-blocking assignments, but that isn't the cause of this problem. Using blocking assignments will lead to race conditions, and you'll have another problem.

Comment: @EML Yes I checked the drivers, actually I think I fixed the problem by moving the `sumOut = out` assignment out of that `if-else` statement and putting it in another `if-else` after that (in this case in `cnt == 1`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by making the below changes. It seemed that the assignment wasn't taking place until after the next clock trigger.

```
if(cnt == 0)
begin
    in1 <= sumIn; 
    in2 <= delta;
    cnt <= cnt + 1;
end
else if(cnt == 1)
begin
    sumOut <= out;
    cnt <= cnt + 1;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to point out that in your reset statement sumOut = 0 has been commented out so its not resetting the register. The other if else might have ended up working because the else got executed by default. Since you only have else if and no else in the code above don't cares got set.

Comment: Yes, that's true. @DBB